# How to import a module that is part of a package that imports another module which is in the same directory of the imported module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My files are in the following structure

```
main_dir/
├─main.py
└─utils/
  ├─func_a.py
  ├─func_b.py
  └─__init__.py
```

The script main.py imports the module func_a.py which imports func_b.py:

main.py

```
from utils import func_a

func_a.hello_world_n_times(5)
```

func_a.py

```
from func_b import hello_world

def hello_world_n_times(n):
    for i in range(n):
        hello_world()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello_world_n_times(5)
```

func_b.py

```
def hello_world():
    print("Hello world!")
```

The file `__init__.py` is empty.

When I run main.py I get the the following error:

```
  File "...\main_dir\utils\func_a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from func_b import hello_world
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'func_b'
```

What's the best approach to solve this error?

Comment: Do note that imports _do not navigate directories_. Imports are only resolved by searching the Python path. In your current design, you're trying to locate both `utils` and `func_b` as _top-level_ packages/modules. That's not going to work. Presumably you want `utils` to be the top-level package, and `func_b.py` to be the module `utils.func_b`.

Answer (score 0):

In func_a.py try:

```
from utils import func_b

def hello_world_n_times(n):
for i in range(n):
    func_b.hello_world()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello_world_n_times(5)
```

I believe that fixes your problem.
you need to **import func_b from utils** as well as add the file path to **hello_world()** in your func_a file

**Main.py:**

```
import func_a
func_a.hello_world_n_times(5)
```

**func_a.py:**

```
from utils import func_b

def hello_world_n_times(n):
    for i in range(n):
        func_b.hello_world()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello_world_n_times(5)
```

**func_b.py:**

```
def hello_world():
    print("Hello World!")
```